# material-ui: AppBar with position="fixed" - scroll on iOS over top overlays AppBar with body background

Tags: material-ui

so - using material-ui v1.2.0 (and in all versions before). I started with the default example from the "Component Demos" / "Drawers" / "Mini variant drawer" example and changed

```
<AppBar position="absolute" className="...">
```

to

```
<AppBar position="fixed" className="...">
```

and now the issue is, that when I scroll down on iOS (tried on several iPads and iPhones) but I'm already at the top, the AppBar is overlaid by the background from the body (see attached screenshot with body {background:gold})

I already played with top:0 and/or adjusting the zIndex, but no success.

[image]

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was able to fix it - remove the

```
root: {... overflow:hidden ...}
```

And it works